Unable to set AutoFilter in .xlsx spreadsheet using xlwings
Using xlwings I'm trying to set an Autofilter on column E of a spreadsheet looking for text "DJM". My code just hangs at the AutoFilter line and does not do anything.
The code snippet is below:
import xlwings as xb
filename = r"djm.xlsx"    
wb = xb.Book(filename)
ws = xb.sheets("BCP")
totalrows = ws.range(1, 1).end('down').row
colrange = "E1:E" + str(totalrows)
ws.api.range(colrange).Autofilter(Field := 5, Criteria1 := "DJM")
wb.close()

I've searched multiple sites, watched multiple videos and I appear to be doing everything right. I'm using PyCharm and Windows 11.

FYI .Autofilter(Field := 5, Criteria1 := "DJM") isn't how you specify keyword arguments in Python - those are positional arguments whose values are assignment expressions.

Thank you everyone - this snippet works:
import xlwings as xw

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set the filepath to the spreadsheet
    filename = r"C:\Temp\djm.xlsx"
    # Open the spreadsheet
    wb = xw.Book(filename)
    # Select the required worksheet
    ws = wb.sheets("BCP")
    # Get the total number of rows from the worksheet
    totalrows = ws.range(1, 1).end('down').row
    # Create the range string using the 'totalrows' variable
    setrange = "A1:F" + str(totalrows)
    # Set the Autofilter on the required worksheet
    ws.api.Range(setrange).AutoFilter(Field := 5, Criteria1 := "DJM")


This code will crash as indicated by @jonrsharpe comment

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
